# Edit the string from particular character to a particular character

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to edit my string. My string is like this `http://www.example.com/example:8080` now what i want to do is find the third occurrence of "/" and then edit the string to `http://www.example.com:8080` so basically remove what ever is between third occurrence of "/" and second occurrence of ":". I tried writing a regular expression and was able to get to the first part it looks like this `((.*?/){3}(.*))` but how to get through the second task and get the final string?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

The number of times the "/" occurs is not a concern guys. It can even be `http://www.example.com/example/index.php:8080` What i want is from the third occurrence of "/" to the second occurrence of ":" the content should be removed or deleted and we finally should have a string as `http://www.example.com:8080`

Comment: Why can't you just replace "/example" in the string using a string's `replace` method?

Comment: You could do `urllib2.urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/example:8080')` and work on the `path` property. Would make the job easier I think.

Comment: @iCodez - because it IS just an 'example' ? ;) It should be more universal than that.

Comment: Why are you even dealing with strings like this? Are you solving the right problem here?

Comment: [Your problem isn't about finding the nth occurence of a character in a string; it's about URL parsing and editing. Ask about URL editing, and you'll get better responses.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @IwoKucharski: That's why I made that a comment and not an answer. I just wanted to let the OP know you can do that.  If all of his strings are of that exact same structure, then Regex is overkill.

Comment: FWIW, `http://www.example.com/example:8080` is a malformed URL. Did you mean to say `http://www.example.com:8080/example` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't accepted an answer, you might be stuck, Here is an example that will do the trick explained by other answers.

```
from urllib2 import urlparse

url = 'http://www.example.com/example:8080'
parsedURL = urlparse.urlparse(url)
port = url.split(':')[2] 
fixedURL = parsedURL.scheme + '://' + parsedURL.netloc + ':' + port
```

The first line accepts the url and parses it
The second line reformats it by cutting out everything after the `/` and before the `:`

This will only work if your port is on the end and there are only 2 `:`s

Comment: yes i'm still waiting for the right way to do it but your answer is again not getting accepted for the longer url's. they might be like `http://www.examples.com/example/my_servlet?_f=20001:80`that is why i was gunning for regex so that what ever might be the string it can bring me back the desired url i.e `http://www.examples.com:80` in this case

Comment: It says list index out of range  @Stephan

Comment: @NottyShinchan think I fixed it, [here](http://pymotw.com/2/urlparse/#module-urlparse) is an example from somebody who knows what they're talking about also, this will only work for valid urls

Comment: The error got changed this time and it says now that the concatenation between 'str' and 'Nonetype' cannot be done! @Stephan

Comment: @NottyShinchan i just tested the code and found why this is happening.  Is your port number always at the end?  If so we can do this very easy.

Comment: Yes it's always gonna be at the end of the string itself

Comment: [We can continue this discussion in a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34553/mads-chat) The updated code should meet your requirements though

Comment: It seems to be working now...thanks for that link even i was able to make my own code with the help of that....Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A simple but ugly way would be:

```
>>> x = 'http://www.example.com/example:8080'
>>> x.find('/',x.find('/',x.find('/')+1)+1)
22
>>> x.rfind(':')
30
>>> x[:22] + x[30:]
'http://www.example.com:8080'
```

Note that `rfind()` searches backwards. Beware this might go wrong if your URL doesn't look as it you expect it to. The `x[:22]` and `x[:30]` parts are examples of slicing, a useful feature of python. For more information, you could read the tutorial for [strings in python.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: What about the end of the string? i.e :8080 ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that originally - I've edited the answer to reflect that. Do read the other comments and answers: if you're really interested in parsing URLs specifically, then you should use something made for the job rather than these general string manipulation methods.

Comment: One more thing, your string is fixed to the number of "/" i showed what if they keep changing like for string `http://www.example.com/example/index.php:8080`

Comment: My example always gives the position of the third '/' character, or -1 if there are fewer than 3 in the string. If there are more, you'll still get the third position - so you'd have to change it if you wanted the fourth.
If you need to be able to find the position of the n'th slash, then you should use a different method.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer to the question but might solve the problem. If that's how the url is always, you could use the `urlparse` module from `urllib2`.

```
In [9]: from urllib2 import urlparse

In [10]: parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse('http://www.example.com/example:8080')

In [11]: parsed_url
Out[11]: ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/example:8080', params='', query='', fragment='')

In [12]: parsed_url.path
Out[12]: '/example:8080'

In [13]: parsed_url.path.split(':')
Out[13]: ['/example', '8080']
```

Rest you can do I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions: use the `urlparse` module (preferred) and regular expression.

```
import urlparse
import re

# METHOD 1: use urlparse
# Parse the incorrect URL
incorrect_url = 'http://www.example.com/example:8080'
scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment =  urlparse.urlparse(incorrect_url)

# Fix up
path, port = path.split(':')
netloc = netloc + ':' + port
path = ''

# Putting them all together
correct_url = urlparse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
print correct_url


# METHOD 2: use regular expression
scheme, dummy1, dummy2, netloc, path, port=re.split(r'[/:]', incorrect_url)
correct_url = '{}://{}:{}'.format(scheme, netloc, port)
print correct_url
```

In general, when dealing with URLs, I prefer the right tool: urlparse. The regular expression solution has the advantage of being shorter, but might get you into trouble for some corner cases.

Comment: The links are just used to be stored in the database that's it i'm fetching them from excel doing string manipulation and storing it. That's why i'm looking to edit the string itself

Comment: I'm trying to work with your 2nd method but it's giving me error stating that too many values too parse once i gave my actual string which has more than 4 "/" in it. Any suggestion? 1st method does the samething too says need more than one value to unpack!

Comment: Please update your question with some examples of URLs which causes trouble, along with the error. I will try my best to help.

Comment: Don't worry brother, @Stephan here helped me out it's working perfectly now. Thanks for your help too. :)